# Can std::function be used to store a function with variadic arguments

Tags: c++, function-pointers, variadic-functions, std-function

I have a structure that I pass around my application which contains a bunch of callback functions:

```
typedef struct {
    std::function<void (void)>    f1;
    std::function<void (int)>     f2;
    std::function<int  (float *)> f3;
    // ... and so on
} CallbackTable;
```

I handle state control within the application by binding different functions to the various callbacks, depending upon the current system state; it works fine.

What I'd now like to do is to add a couple of extra callbacks with signatures containing variable numbers of arguments, akin to printf: for example,

```
    std::function<int  (const char * format, ...)> printToStdOut;
```

This *doesn't* work. In Visual C++, I get an error message stating:

```
error C2027: use of undefined type 'std::_Get_function_impl<_Fty>'
```

I'm still feeling my way through this area of C++ syntax and would very much appreciate any advice on how I should proceed from here. My overriding objective is to be able to make a call along the lines of:

```
myCallbackTable.printToStdOut("I've just eaten %d bananas\r\n", nBananas);
```

...and to have the output directed to a console, to a file or to a GUI window, according to the system state.

Comment: If it is just output you are interested in you should use an [`std::ostream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/ostream/) instead.

Comment: `std::function` is only defined for function types of the form `R(ArgTypes...)`, where `ArgTypes...` is a pack expansion of a type parameter pack (i.e., a (possibly empty) list of types). So, no C-style variadic functions allowed.

Comment: AFAIK no specialization of `std::function` for variadic functions, see a possible work around [here](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/467086/stdfunction-with-several-or-none-parameters#post2034402), not sure if its related.

Answer (score 5):

Edit: Original answer was wrong, modified but still may not be a good answer, leaving it here for educational purposes:

Many variable argument functions have a va_list version. `printf` for example has `vprintf`. These variants explicitly take a va_list instead of an ellipses.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdarg>


int main()
{
   std::function<int(const char*,va_list)> test2(vprintf);

   return 0;
}
```

Invoking it, however, is a pain.

```
int invoke_variadic(const std::function<int(const char*,va_list)>& ref,const char* a ,...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args,a);
    ref(a,args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

What was wrong with original post (thanks /u/T.C.): `std::function<int(const char*,va_list)> test2(printf)` compiles, which I took to meaning it "worked". However it compiles because printf can accept arguments of any type (including a va_list), and `std::function` only checks if it can be invoked in that way.

Comment: So does `std::function<int(const char*,int)> test2(printf);`, or even `std::function<int(const char*,int, double, float)> test2(printf);`. It compiles because `...` can match anything, not because it's somehow a synonym for `va_list` (it most certainly is not).

Comment: @T.C. You are right...I cannot explain why all of it compiles. I'm still not exactly sure what is going on, but it doesn't actually take a va_list...there is a va_list variant of printf, however, so I'm changing my answer to reflect that. Got any explanation on why it accepts that? It does, indeed, "work" after defining the input types...

Comment: It works because you *can* indeed invoke `printf` with that list of arguments and get back something implicitly convertible to `int` (assuming of course that there's no UB caused by wrong format strings etc.). `std::function` doesn't actually care about the type of the thing it is storing, only that it can be invoked in the way specified in the template parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from what @MadScienceDreams suggested, this has worked rather well for me...

Firstly, I defined variable-argument versions of the std::function objects in the struct, then used the fact that this is C++ not C to add some methods as well:

```
typedef struct {
    std::function<void (void)>    f1;
    std::function<void (int)>     f2;
    std::function<int  (float *)> f3;
    // ... and so on

    std::function<int  (const char * format, va_list args)> vprintToStdOut; 
    std::function<int  (const char * format, va_list args)> vprintToStdErr;

    int printToStdOut(const char * format, ...)
    {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, format);
        int count = vprintToStdOut(format, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        return count;
    }

    int printToStdErr(const char * format, ...)
    {
        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, format);
        int count = vprintToStdErr(format, ap);
        va_end(ap);
        return count;
    }

} CallbackTable;
```

The default implementations of the variable-argument functions, for console output, were then (after having declared 'using namespace std::placeholders;' without which the syntax is unmanageable):

```
myCallbackTable.vprintToStdOut = std::bind(vfprintf, stdout, _1, _2);
myCallbackTable.vprintToStdErr = std::bind(vfprintf, stderr, _1, _2);
```

...and from this point, I can use exactly the syntax I was hoping to use:

```
myCallbackTable.printToStdOut("I like to eat at least %d bananas a day\r\n", nBananas);
```